# moving from ng-include to ngRoute

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to Angular and learned the basics about it recently.

In my current project, I am developing a single page application. As of now, my HTML/JS setup is as per below:

HTML:

```
<body>
    <ng-include src='"src/includes/home.html"'></ng-include>
    <!-- home.html is the HTML template with static data -->
</body>
```

app.js:

```
    'use strict';

    var app = angular.module('MyApp',['home']);

    angular                 
    .module('home', [])
    .directive('homeDir', function(){
       return {
        replace: true,
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'src/includes/home.html'
      };
    });
```

This code is working fine but I would like to introduce routing to have better control over the pages, instead of using `ng-include`.

So now, my HTML looks the same and I actually dont know what to change in it while using routing.

My app.js now looks like this:

```
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('MyApp',['home']);

// trying to introduce routing:

angular
.module('home', ['ngResource', 'ngRoute'])
.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider'],
    function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
        $routeProvider.
        when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'src/includes/home.html',
            controller: 'homeCtrl'
        }).
        when('/drawer', {
            redirectTo: 'src/includes/home.html#drawer',
            controller: 'drawerCtrl'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });

        // use the HTML5 History API
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    }
);

app.controller('homeCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.message = "some message";
    console.log("homeCtrl called");
});

app.controller('drawerCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.message = "some other message";
    console.log("drawerCtrl called");
});
```

However, I am getting an error:

```
Error: error:modulerr
Module Error
```

As per the link following the error:

```
This error occurs when a module fails to load due to some exception.
```

Why is it not loading? What am I missing? What should I change the HTML to?

**UPDATE:**

After including `angular-route.min.js`, I am getting the error:

```
Error: whole is undefined
beginsWith@file:///D:/projects/svn/trunk/src/libs/angular.js:8729:1
LocationHtml5Url/this.$$parse@file:///D:/projects/svn/trunk/src/libs/angular.js:8772:9
$LocationProvider/this.$get<@file:///D:/projects/svn/trunk/src/libs/angular.js:9269:5
invoke@file:///D:/projects/svn/trunk/src/libs/angular.js:3762:7
createInjector/instanceCache.$injector<@file:///D:/projects/svn/trunk/src/libs/angular.js:3604:13
getService@file:///D:/projects/svn/trunk/src/libs/angular.js:3725:11
invoke@file:///D:/projects/svn/trunk/src/libs/angular.js:3752:1
createInjector/instanceCache.$injector<@file:///D:/projects/svn/trunk/src/libs/angular.js:3604:13
getService@file:///D:/projects/svn/trunk/src/libs/angular.js:3725:11
invoke@file:///D:/projects/svn/trunk/src/libs/angular.js:3752:1
registerDirective/</<@file:///D:/projects/svn/trunk/src/libs/angular.js:5316:21
forEach@file:///D:/projects/svn/trunk/src/libs/angular.js:322:7
registerDirective/<@file:///D:/projects/svn/trunk/src/libs/angular.js:5314:13
invoke@file:///D:/projects/svn/trunk/src/libs/angular.js:3762:7
createInjector/instanceCache.$injector<@file:///D:/projects/svn/trunk/src/libs/angular.js:3604:13
getService@file:///D:/projects/svn/trunk/src/libs/angular.js:3725:11
addDirective@file:///D:/projects/svn/trunk/src/libs/angular.js:6363:28
collectDirectives@file:///D:/projects/svn/trunk/src/libs/angular.js:5801:1
compileNodes@file:///D:/projects/svn/trunk/src/libs/angular.js:5666:1
compileNodes@file:///D:/projects/svn/trunk/src/libs/angular.js:5682:1
compileNodes@file:///D:/projects/svn/trunk/src/libs/angular.js:5682:1
compile@file:///D:/projects/svn/trunk/src/libs/angular.js:5603:1
bootstrap/doBootstrap/</<@file:///D:/projects/svn/trunk/src/libs/angular.js:1343:11
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$eval@file:///D:/projects/svn/trunk/src/libs/angular.js:12077:9
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$apply@file:///D:/projects/svn/trunk/src/libs/angular.js:12175:11
bootstrap/doBootstrap/<@file:///D:/projects/svn/trunk/src/libs/angular.js:1341:9
invoke@file:///D:/projects/svn/trunk/src/libs/angular.js:3762:7
bootstrap/doBootstrap@file:///D:/projects/svn/trunk/src/libs/angular.js:1340:8
bootstrap@file:///D:/projects/svn/trunk/src/libs/angular.js:1353:5
angularInit@file:///D:/projects/svn/trunk/src/libs/angular.js:1301:37
@file:///D:/projects/svn/trunk/src/libs/angular.js:21050:5
jQuery.Callbacks/fire@file:///D:/projects/svn/trunk/src/libs/jquery-1.9.1.min.js:1037:1
jQuery.Callbacks/self.fireWith@file:///D:/projects/svn/trunk/src/libs/jquery-1.9.1.min.js:1148:7
.ready@file:///D:/projects/svn/trunk/src/libs/jquery-1.9.1.min.js:433:38
completed@file:///D:/projects/svn/trunk/src/libs/jquery-1.9.1.min.js:103:4

file:///D:/projects/svn/trunk/src/libs/angular.js
Line 9511
```

**Edit:**

Here are my HTML imports:

```
<head>
    <title></title>

    <!--    External libraries  -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="src/css/font-awesome-4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="src/css/headers.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="src/css/drawer.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="src/css/custom.css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="src/libs/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="src/libs/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="src/libs/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="src/libs/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="src/libs/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="src/libs/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="src/libs/angular-pull-to-refresh.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="src/libs/nprogress.js"></script>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="src/libs/ng-modal.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="src/libs/angular-route.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="src/js/jssor-slider-plugin/jssor.core.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="src/js/jssor-slider-plugin/jssor.utils.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="src/js/jssor-slider-plugin/jssor.slider.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="src/js/app.js"></script>

    <script>
        document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
    </script>
</head>
```

Comment: Can you share you imports in your markup ? the order is important.

Comment: @benek Please see my edit above.

Comment: Something that will help : please reference angular without minification and same as angular-route. You will be able to break and see the detail of the error (instead of "a" undefined...). Also remove angular-ui-router.js since your are only using the angular basic router and not ui-router which is completly different.

Comment: @benek Question updated.

Comment: It looks like you 'home' app is defined too times. The second removes the first one : .module('home', ['ngResource', 'ngRoute']) and .module('home', [])... Can you clarify your code to have only one app.module('home' , [dependencies]) and the others with the syntax : app.module('home')...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Config section is incorrect. Instead of

```
.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider'], function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) { ... });
```

it should be

```
.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) { ... }]);
```

Note, that function definition belongs to array object.

Another mistake is in `redirectTo` property of the `drawer` route, currently it doesn't make sense. You want probably this instead:

```
.when('/drawer', {
    templateUrl: 'src/includes/drawer.html',
    controller: 'drawerCtrl'
 })
```

Comment: I made the changes that you suggested, but I am still getting that error.

Comment: Make sure you have `ngView` directive as well. Take a look at [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/K23b5khgJ1iMHWffwRgw?p=preview) demo.

Comment: In your demo, you are not loading the data from the template HTML. I need to do that in my project. I tried [modifying your demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/9FCDtFnh2EZV3xqdCD1g?p=preview), but it didnt work.

Comment: You should use templateUrl, I used `template` just to demonstration http://plnkr.co/edit/sJzAwnE6yVkhcXmFFCJw?p=preview

Comment: It works well in the demo, but locally on my machine, I am getting an error mentioned in the update in the question.

Comment: I also downloaded the demo and tried to run it locally. It gave the same error. Do I have to use a HTTP server for this? like Apache?

Comment: Yes, you can't use file:// protocol (Chrome doesn't allow it by default). You should use server.

Answer (score 3):

Ensue that you have added the `angular-route.js` file to the html file.
And you are missing the ngRoute module here -

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp',['ngRoute','ngResource' ]);
app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){... }]);
```

dfsq is correct. There are syntax errors in the code.

Comment: No, module `home` defines `ngRoute` dependency, so it's okay. No need to declare it on `Amazon` module again.

Comment: yeah, didn't notice it. tx.

Comment: @Rabi I have included `angular-route.min.js` in my HTML, not `ng-route.js`

Comment: @Rabi After including `angular-route.min.js`, I am getting the error `Error: a is undefined` followed by numerous URLs, pointing to angular library.