# Jssor Slider not working in Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jssor

I am using **jssor** slider in `angular` , means Images will be dynamic and comes from db. I'll loop over multiple images using `ng-repeat` .

**Here is my code :**

```
"<div ng-repeat='image in images'> <img u=\"thumb\" src=\" {$ image.path $} /" />\n<img u=\"{$ image.path $} \" /></div>"
```

I have tried few more things to debug like used `ng-repeat` but image src is static

```
<div ng-repeat='image in images'> {$ image $} <img u=\"thumb\" src=\"http://cdn1.spiegel.de/images/image-52390-galleryV9-cxso.jpg\" />\n<img u=\"image\" src=\"http://cdn1.spiegel.de/images/image-52390-galleryV9-cxso.jpg\" /></div>"
```

This above code will print {$ image $} but slides will not work .

But if I'll remove `ng-repeat` from `<div>` then slider will work properly .

**EDIT :**

Here is the plunk I created http://plnkr.co/edit/QEkjMREOUuzFugctt6fw?p=preview    . 
Angular code start at `line no 123 index.html`

If you remove angular ng-repeat and add static images to slider . It will work .

Comment: This link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26135139/moving-from-ng-include-to-ngroute may help.

Comment: Note that angular renders first, and jssor slider goes after. Please double check if the html code rendered by angular is correct or not before jssor slider initializes.

Comment: @jssor  In my case I am rendering HTML code first (including jssor code) and then angular . Means I am using Python as backend and Python renders HTML and provide response to angular and in angular I am making angular scope available using directive  ```<div dynamic="scopeVar"></div>```

Comment: You should get angular rendered correctly and then initialize jssor slider.

Answer (score 1):

I tried your plunkr and allimages was not in $scope.
You did not seem to initialise the controller in the correct way.

I changed the following:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
```

and in script.js

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", [ ]);

app.controller("Ctrl", function ($scope) { ... }
```

[See updated plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/DTUUlamGyU4yFZFknVKb?p=preview) (Images are shown, no sliding though, but it will help you get on track)

or check out https://github.com/adebisi-fa/dang-jssor (Jssor angular directive)

Comment: ```{$ image $}``` is a debug code and ```u``` is an attribute used by jssor plugin

Comment: Does the above code work? If not, provide a plunk for people to test and try out your code.

Comment: I have edited my answer with a plunkr url :) . Good luck

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    function Ctrl($scope) {
        $scope.allimages = [
        {
            "pk": "291512b7-d72e-4341-9f2e-226f55421318",
            "content": {
                "fields": [
                  "title",
                  "image"
                ],
                "image": "http://www.hdwallpapers.in/walls/green_sea_view-wide.jpg",
                "title": "Lorem Ipsum 0"
            }
        },
        {
            "pk": "1adeeac2-5963-4bbf-9fb7-c55b1d9b8dea",
            "content": {
                "fields": [
                  "title",
                  "image"
                ],
                "image": "https://theartgalleryumd.files.wordpress.com/2011/10/dsc0017.jpg",
                "title": "Lorem Ipsum 0"
            }
        },
        {
            "pk": "e021f394-64af-42a8-88ae-daa013f74397",
            "content": {
                "fields": [
                  "title",
                  "image"
                ],
                "image": "http://cdn1.spiegel.de/images/image-52390-galleryV9-cxso.jpg",
                "title": "Lorem Ipsum 0"
            }
        }
        ];

        $scope.postBind = function () {
            if ($scope.databound) {
                jssor_slider1_starter('slider1_container');
            }
            else {
                $scope.databound = true;
            }
        };
    }
</script>


<div u="slides" style="cursor: move; position: absolute; left: 240px; top: 0px; width: 720px; height: 480px; overflow: hidden;">
    <div ng-repeat="image in allimages">
        <img u="image" src="{{image.content.image}}" />
        <img u="thumb" src="{{image.content.image}}" />
    </div>
</div>
{{postBind()}}
```